# Expose kvm to Docker container without --privileged

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization

Is it possible to allow `qemu-kvm` execution inside Docker container without full `--privileged` mode (by enabling only kvm-related devices/capabilities, following the principle of least privilege)? I've tried to simply add `-v /dev/kvm:/dev/kvm:rw`, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: Have you tried `--device /dev/kvm:/dev/kvm`?